# ¿como crear elementos sobre un conjunto de elementos html, bootstap?

Tags: javascript, java, html5, bootstrap, css3

Que tal gente estoy desarrollando este proyecto que muestra las posiciones donde deberia estar un objeto, el problema esque al no encontrar con que diagramar, cree una matriz de divs, los cuales cada que pasa un objeto pinto el conjunto de divs acorde a sus posiciones ("sus ids"), el problema esque yo cree esa tabla de encima para hacer un tipo index, pero me parece un poco laborioso ver la tabla y luego la matriz,

entonces mi duda es como puedo crear un elemento div  u otro sobre esa matriz que coloree
mi idea general es decir toma las pociones que recibo y crea un div sobre ellas pero no se como hacer esto espero haberme explicado o poder recibir su valiosa ayuda

**Creo la Matriz**

````
                            <div class="col bg-light text-dark"><%= hora%></div>
                            <%
                                for (int j = 1; j < 55; j++) {
                                    if (i == 0) {
                                        out.println("<div id='" + i + "" + j + "' class='col bg-dark text-white'>" + j + "</div>");

                                    } else {
                            %>

                            <div id="f<%= i + "c" + j%>" class="col bg-light text-white div10"> </div>
                            <%

                                    }
                                }
                            %>

                        </div> ```

**Coloreo segun los datos que recibo **

``` $(document).ready(function () {

                //let colores = ["0d6efd", "6610f2", "6f42c1", "d63384", "dc3545", "fd7e14", "ffc107", "198754", "20c997", "0dcaf0"];
                //console.log(colores.length)
                var a = 0;
                var cont = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
                    color(lista[i][0], lista[i][1], lista[i][2], lista[i][3], lista[i][4], lista[i][5], lista[i][6], lista[i][7]);
                }

                function color(barco, fecha, fecha2, hora_i, hora_f, bita_inicial, bita_final, fechadia) {
                    //console.log(fecha, fecha2, hora_i, hora_f, bita_inicial, bita_final);
                    //document.getElementById("td"+a).className = "div" + a + "";
                    //console.log(document.getElementById("td"+a));
                    const tiempoTranscurrido = Date.now();
                    var hoy = new Date(tiempoTranscurrido);
                    var ini = new Date(fecha);
                    var fin = new Date(fecha2);

                    var date = fechadia;
                    var newdate = date.split("/").reverse().join("/");


                    var f1 = new Date(newdate);
                    hoy.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    ini.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    fin.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    f1.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    console.log("fecha f1: " + f1);
                    //console.log("fecha fin: "+fin);


                    hora_i = +hora_i;
                    hora_f = +hora_f;
                    bita_inicial = +bita_inicial;
                    bita_final = +bita_final + 1;
                    if (ini.getTime() == f1.getTime()) {

                        //  console.log("es igual");
                    }
                    if (ini.getTime() < f1.getTime()) {
                        hora_i = 1;
                        //   console.log("es menor");
                    }
                    if (fin.getTime() > f1.getTime()) {
                        hora_f = 24;
                        // console.log("es mayor");
                    }
                    for (let i = hora_i; i <= hora_f; i++) {
                        for (let j = bita_inicial; j < bita_final; j++) {
                            //console.log(j);
                            try {
                                document.getElementById("f" + i + "c" + j).className = "col div" + a + " text-white";
                                const demoId = document.querySelector('#f' + i + 'c' + j);

                                //data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top"
                                demoId.setAttribute('data-bs-toggle', 'tooltip');
                                demoId.setAttribute('data-bs-placement', 'top');
                                demoId.setAttribute('title', barco);
                                //console.log(demoId);

                                var exampleEl = document.getElementById("f" + i + "c" + j);
                                var tooltip = new bootstrap.Tooltip(exampleEl, {
                                    boundary: document.body // or document.querySelector('#boundary')
                                });

                            } catch (e) {
                                console.log(e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    a++;
                }

            });
````

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]